# How to fix refreshPreferences Message in Xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode

add this line code to my class

```
let myLayer = CALayer()
myLayer.contents = self.makeTrySwiftLogoImage().CGImage

var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -500
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, 45.0f * M_PI / 180.0, 0, 1, 0)
myLayer.transform = transform
```

and get this message to my console

2017-09-22 18:00:53.354890+0330 SibDiet[973:944502] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 0
2017-09-22 18:00:53.355974+0330 SibDiet[973:944502] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
2017-09-22 18:00:53.356014+0330 SibDiet[973:944502] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0

and don't run my application, remove this 6 line and run again but receive this message again, remove Xcode and install again but no fix

Comment: The same topic:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392382/how-to-fix-refreshpreferences-hangtracerenabled-and-hangtracerduration-message-i/46469643#46469643)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix it on High Sierra(10.13.1) XCode 9.1 and with iOS 11.0.3 by defining **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE** as **disable** by going in XCode via

> Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Arguments > Environment Variables
>
> add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disable
> schema editor (fragment)[image]

*Note: NSLog may not work after doing this.*

**Similar issue is reported in the question:**

### refreshPreferences HangTracerEnabled / HangTracerDuration messages in iOS 11 + Xcode 9

Comment: I believe I fulfil the critique had been made