# refreshPreferences HangTracerEnabled / HangTracerDuration messages in iOS 11 + Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

When update to iOS 11, after run app in iPhone, I receive this message in Xcode console:

```
SibDiet[924:111682] refreshPreferences: HangTracerEnabled: 0
SibDiet[924:111682] refreshPreferences: HangTracerDuration: 500
SibDiet[924:111682] refreshPreferences: ActivationLoggingEnabled: 0 ActivationLoggingTaskedOffByDA:0
```

And now I get this message in every simulator and app.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can hide this message with click left mouse button on your target, and next `Edit Scheme`.

[image: hide]

After that in section `Environment Variables` create  variable with name `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` and value `disable` as on the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and also can you describe what this message means?

Answer (score 7):

At this point, there are no data to suggest that you need to respond to this spewing of internal debugger status.  BTW, these messages also appear when developing on physical devices, not just simulators.

The prior answer of disabling the Xcode Environment Variable OS_ACTIVITY_MODE will stop all such internal system messages with the unfortunate side effect of turning off console logging from `NSLog()` calls in ObjC. I have not checked, but it may also disable Swift `print()` logging.

The Xcode team should really discriminate between disabling system logging and user logging!

Comment: Yes, it throws out my baby with their bath water.

Comment: No! setting `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to disable doesn't disable `print()` logging

Answer (score 1):

## It seems the **(refresh preferences...)** problem appears on multiple platforms.

I managed to fix it  on *High Sierra(10.13.1)* *XCode 9.1* and with *iOS 11.0.3* by defining **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE** as **disable** by going in XCode via

> Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Arguments > Environment Variables
>
> add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disable

[image: schema editor (fragment)]

**Note: NSLog may not work after doing this.**

**Similar issue is reported in the question:**

### How to fix refreshPreferences Message in Xcode 9 [duplicate]

Comment: Yes, as noted, this will turn off the console logging of internal messages from the system, but at the expense of disabling NSLog and Print.  In many cases, this is too high a price to pay for ignoring junk or noise from the system.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Let Apple give a comprehensive solution... Anyway I will look  more into this, NSLog pisses me off too.